Order between the solutions of linear recursions
We consider the following 4 linear recursions:
$$
\begin{array}{llll}
u_{n+3}& = \frac 12 u_{n+2} & + \frac 14 u_{n+1} & + \frac 18 u_n \\
v_{n+3} & = \frac 12  v_{n+2}  &+ \frac 12 v_{n+1} &- \frac 18 v_n \\w_{n+3} & = w_{n+2}  &  -  \frac 14 w_{n+1} & + \frac 18 w_n \\
z_{n+3}& = z_{n+2} & &  - \frac 18 z_n
\end{array}
$$
with the same initial conditions $(1,1,1)$ for the first three terms $(u_0, u_1,u_2), (v_0, v_1,v_2), \ldots$
I would like to prove the following inequality (checked by numerical computations):
$$u_n \geq v_n \geq w_n \geq z_n, \quad  n \geq 0$$
with in fact strict inequalities for $n$ large enough. I would prefer soft arguments based on the structures of the equations than using e.g. the explicit solutions, but any argument that reveals the structure of the problem will be great !
--
(More generally I am interested in tools for proving inequalities between solutions of linear recurrences - in the sense : when is it possible to order the solutions for each $n$ ? I suspect the topic has already been studied).

If a recursive equation is linear and the coefficients of terms of any order are constant, then you can usually solve it using the time shift property of transformations. The most popular would be the Z-transform, Laplace transform and the Fourier transform. Then you would only have to compare the solutions.

$u_n\geq v_n \geq w_n \geq z_n, \quad  n \geq 0$ is not true

My bad ! Where does it fail ?

Have you tried a proof by induction?

@Olivier perhaps you have a typo. At the moment, $v_4=0.75$ and $w_4=0.8125$.

Thanks I'll check !

@ChrisLewis : My bad, I interverted $v$ and $w$, this should be OK now !

@ClaudeLeibovici Same comment ! Thank you both !

I believe "finding closed form solution of the sequences and then compare them" is the easiest, fastest method

This problem is solved in Guibas Odlyzko (1981) Section 7 @ClaudeLeibovici

This precise problem is solved in Guibas Odlyzko (1981) Section 7 @NN2
